# ASP.NET MVC 3 + jQuery is not working after MVC Tools Update?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm wondering what happen with jQuery using on ASP.NET MVC any jQuery code is not working specially in click methods

I'm using Razor view engines.

Any notice about this issue?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.simpledialog').simpleDialog();
});

$('#button').click(function(){
    //ToDo
});
```

I've added the dialog script and css :

```
 <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it always breaks when button is clicked and I receive an error :

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error : 
    Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'
```

Comment: We need a bit more information than just 'is not working' to help you. Can you add some code? The default project template uses jQuery 1.5.1 after the update are you referencing the jquery-1.5.1.js file and not the older jquery-1.4.2.js?

Comment: I'm trying to use modal dialogs, I added some snipet

Comment: Make sure the simpledialog plugin file exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the solution above does not work and you're also using Telerik controls, you should add .jQuery(false) to the ScriptRegistrar tag at the bottom of your Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml file. If you don't do this, the asset.axd call is *also* loading (blindly) jQuery.

Comment: I come out with this solution using .jQuery(false)

Answer (score 1):

Check what jQuery your Scripts folder contains and then check your Layout.cshtml, if it has reference to correct file. There might be differences in versions.

Edit: Also do check the `packages.config` file in your MVC application root directory. There is a reference to jQuery package. So you might need to correct it to your actual version, or remove that jQuery package.

Comment: @Dampe, jQuery version 1.5.1 is installed via nuget also I remove and add manually and seems no changes. I updated the post with the Error

Comment: @Angel Escobedo: I don't see that error anywhere. Have you checked packages.config? If it won't help, plase add content of that packages.config file into your question together with html head from _Layout.cshtml and write what version of jQuery is in Scripts folder.

Comment: I also tried that, i dont think that the problem should be jQuery

Comment: Well that error message makes it much cleaner ;) I do not know what are you using for that dialog, but problem is obviously with dialog. Are you referencing correct script and are you trying to use it on correct element with right options?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about that could you provide me another script for modal dialog? thanks

Comment: @Angel Escobedo: MVC 3 comes already with jQuery UI, so why not use modal from that? You can see demos [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if it helps anyone, but i had this problem for ages - then realised one of my partial views for including a free calendar control was referencing an earlier version of jQuery and stopping the dialog from working!

Comment: Yes, I thought it happened to me before.